# lftp certificate suddenly not trusted

Tags: ftp, ssl, certificates

Since one week ago, lftp does not validate one of the root certificates on my system

```
Certificate: CN=www.planete-sciences.org    
 Issued by:        C=US,O=Let's Encrypt,CN=R3
 Checking against: C=US,O=Let's Encrypt,CN=R3
  Trusted
Certificate: C=US,O=Let's Encrypt,CN=R3
 Issued by:        C=US,O=Internet Security Research Group,CN=ISRG Root X1
 Checking against: C=US,O=Internet Security Research Group,CN=ISRG Root X1
  Trusted
Certificate: C=US,O=Internet Security Research Group,CN=ISRG Root X1
 Issued by: O=Digital Signature Trust Co.,CN=DST Root CA X3
ERROR: Certificate verification: Not trusted (93:3C:6D:DE:E9:5C:9C:41:A4:0F:9F:50:49:3D:82:BE:03:AD:87:BF)
**** Certificate verification: Not trusted (93:3C:6D:DE:E9:5C:9C:41:A4:0F:9F:50:49:3D:82:BE:03:AD:87:BF)
---- Fermeture du socket de contrôle
ls: Erreur fatale: Certificate verification: Not trusted (93:3C:6D:DE:E9:5C:9C:41:A4:0F:9F:50:49:3D:82:BE:03:AD:87:BF)
```

Both filezilla and firefox trust these certificates.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: does anyone have a solution for the client side or know of an alternative client that isn't EOL?

Answer (score 3):

I have exactly the same issue. I think it could be a temporary issue with certificates/chains updates, but I can't find any evidence: a colleague of mine can login to the same ftps instance without any errors.  As a workaround you could manually add the missing certificate. The following command:

```
    openssl s_client -connect www.planete-sciences.org:21 -starttls ftp -showcerts
```

should retrieve the full certificate chain for your ftp server. Copy the *ISRG Root X1* certificate (the last block enclosed by `--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--` and `--END CERTIFICATE--`, tags included) and past it in a new file, for example `.lftp/mycert.crt`. Next add the full path of your custom certificate file in `.lftp/rc` file, for example:

```
    set ssl:ca-file "/home/paolo/.lftp/mycert.crt"
```

This will fix the issue. You can find other workaround [like this](https://serverfault.com/a/727003), which suggests to disable ssl in your conf file (not recommended) or add the certificate system wide (however, I prefer to add a local workaround). Updating certificates as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095714/4385116) seems not working to me (maybe is a temporary issue?). If you want to disable ssl, there's also the possibility to doing this for a particular domain, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063645/4385116).

Hope this helps

Comment: It is even easier to obtain the certificate: Just download this: https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrg-root-x1-cross-signed.pem to Downloads directory. Then use set ssl:ca-file "~/Downloads/isrg-root-x1-cross-signed.pem"

Comment: When I run that openSSL command I don't see a certificate printed. I just see: "CONNECTED(00000003)" whereas I can still connect to it just file using FileZilla so I know it's not a connection issue

Answer (score 2):

"DST Root CA X3" [expired](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/), and `lftp` implemented its own [broken chain verification](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/641).

If you are the server admin you could switch to the alternate chain (with self-signed `ISRG Root X1`), which should fix the problem with `lftp` - but [breaks older android clients](https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html).

Comment: Yes, DST Root CCA X3 actually expired, but lftp fails verification for cross signed variant of ISRG Root X1 which is an root certificate for itself